# Why isn't Pot of Greed, or any banned card, instead errata-ed?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

They/Konami/Whoever errata-ed Dark Magician of Chaos, [four times in fact](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Errata:Dark_Magician_of_Chaos).

[Dumb question](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-%E2%80%93-and-answer-them/): Why not to Pot of Greed or any of the Match Winners?

Guesses:

- T/K/W expect that the card **may be unbanned** with the introduction of new cards like Thousand-Eyes Restrict where, afaik, it became unlimited without errata (Edit: Oh ok so it was actually [errata-ed 5 times](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Errata:Thousand-Eyes_Restrict). Wait, so what's the difference between original and current?) after previously being banned (for way too long considering Honor Ark).
- **[OCG vs TCG](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/41787)**: But come on, Pot of Greed will [inherently never be unbanned by the ontology/philosophy/nature/idk of trading card games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32511/why-is-pot-of-greed-banned#comment57186_32513).
- Pot of Greed I guess could come back if the 40 card minimum is increased. Idk.
- Pot of Greed could be kept banned an un-errata-ed for the traditional players.
- Money that comes from making new cards instead of letting players use their old Pot of Greed cards to represent the errata-ed Pot of Greed
- There may not necessarily be a way to change the Pot of Greed effect that is not to a radical* extent.

*I use 'radical' s.t. Dark Magician of Chaos did not undergo a 'radical' change. For a better word/phrasing, please suggest.

Related:

[Why is Pot of Greed banned?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32511/why-is-pot-of-greed-banned)

Comment: This Q is asking for developer intent, thing that only Trollnami knows for sure... will attempt to answer when I get to PC

Comment: @DarkCygnus Answer attempt means [not off-topic](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/41588/how-can-final-countdown-be-exploited?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment57001_41677) please and thanks? :D

Comment: The cards only text is to draw 2 cards, what are you going to eratta it to? Even if you add something like discarding cards it is still pretty powerful.

Comment: @JoeW I was thinking something like the exact Pot of Desires effect but change the Pot of Greed picture. I rather like the Pot of Desires picture though.

Comment: Sounds like the didn’t eratta it because they replaced it with a different card.

Comment: You don't use errata to turn one card into a different card, you just ban the first and print more of the second. No silliness with old editions or updates involved.

Comment: Simple answer: Because there would be **way too many cards out there**

Comment: @Nij Right but why exactly? Edited question for clarification.

Comment: @VortexYT Too many new cards means too much money? Eg Creating Pot of Desires means more money for Konami. Or too many errata-ed cards means too much choices in deck building? Eg Errata-ed Pot of Greed means more decisions to make in deck building.

Answer (score 1):

> Why not to Pot of Greed or any of the Match Winners?

First, the **"Match Winner" cards cannot be used in an official event, so no point in changing their text**. They are "just" prize cards given to World Champions. If you want refer to a previous [answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/40207/22373) of mine regarding such cards.

Also, **there *have* been banned cards that had their effects errata'd**, one example that comes to mind is [Ring of Destruction](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Ring_of_destruction). They did the errata just before they un-banned that card, so it is more balanced and has less abuse potential.

Now, as you correctly point out, I also think there is virtually **no way Pot of Greed is coming back**. As explained in the Q's you linked, it is basically a "draw 2 cards for NO COST at all", something that is extremely unbalanced.

My guess is that **if** they ever errata Pot of Greed, is because they may be thinking of un-banning it, but surely it's effect will no longer be the same as before.

Comment: DarkCygnus, thanks. 1. about match winners, i was thinking something like 'if this card is xyz summoned, if your opponent surrenders, your opponent loses the match'. idk. 2. about unbanned, so why not for others? 3. Pot of Greed: oh you mean, errata-ing Pot of Greed is indeed possibly on Konami's to do list? I mean, what makes you say that? Have they ever indicated such a plan to errata all cards s.t. none are banned? Or does it/does it not make sense for some reason to do such? also, i edited question for clarification.

Comment: (bump 4 years later) DarkCygnus, thanks. 1. about match winners, i was thinking something like 'if this card is xyz summoned, if your opponent surrenders, your opponent loses the match'. idk. 2. about unbanned, so why not for others? 3. Pot of Greed: oh you mean, errata-ing Pot of Greed is indeed possibly on Konami's to do list? I mean, what makes you say that? Have they ever indicated such a plan to errata all cards s.t. none are banned? Or does it/does it not make sense for some reason to do such? also, i edited question for clarification.

Comment: The key part in my answer regarding the errata is the "My guess is that...". I'm not saying that it will be unbanned nor erratae'd. I'm saying that **if** they someday make an errata, **then** it could mean they may be thinking of un-banning it... regarding your other questions those are more fit for chat I guess :) as they are open for discussion