# Why are the OCG and TCG banlists radically different?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

From [wiki](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/September_2013_Lists):

> As of September 2013, the OCG and TCG have had different banlists, with multiple cards in fact being Forbidden in one list but Unlimited in the other (in both directions).

[Dumb question](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-%E2%80%93-and-answer-them/): How could banlists be so ***radically*** different?

Guess: This has something to do with some cards' being [TCG-only](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/TCG-only) xor [OCG-only](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/OCG-only).

- If so, then **what specifically** are some of these cards that may influence the ***radical*** banlist differences, and why?

For other reasons , what and why?

Answer (score 5):

> How could banlists be so radically different?

Well, TCG (Trading Card Game) and OCG (**Official** Card Game) are **two separate and different games actually**; you can't use cards from one on official games from the other. I am not Konami, but seems logical to me that such lists exist separately.

As you probably know, Yu-Gi-Oh! started first as a Manga, and then an Anime went out (and then translations). Only after some time later is that the OCG was created, and shortly after the TCG. We can see that since it's inception they were conceived differently and for different target audiences.

Another reason that justifies different lists is the fact that **cards first come out on OCG, and some time later they appear (or not) on TCG** in the latest Booster set available.

This means that for a period of time some cards actually don't exist on the TCG and are legally unable to be played on official events. This shows that OCG has different needs/situations, and at different moments, than TCG regarding the cards that need buffing, nerfing, or erratas.

Comment: '...some cards actually don't exist...' --> Thanks but again 'So like what are these cards, and what role, if any, do these have to play in the radical banlist differences?'

Comment: Well, what if one of those cards needs to be limited, banned, semi-limited or unrestricted? Every card must have one of those categories. It wouldn't make sense for people on TCG to have such card on "their list" if it actually doesn't exist for them. The key argument here is that OCG and TCG are actually different games, thus different rules, bans, etc.

Comment: Any specifics pretty please with sugar on top?

Comment: @BCLC well, a quick look on the OCG Banlist I found that [Ancient Fairy Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Fairy_Dragon) is forbidden (to my surprise, actually). On TCG, this card is unrestricted, but the reason *why* this the ban on OCG only Konami knows (perhaps people were abusing it on the OCG but not on the TCG events, thus no need to ban it there also).

Comment: DarkCygnus, I meant to ask which OCG-only or which TCG-only cards influence the banlist differences and how. I'm guessing that's the only or at least main reason why the banlists are different. Thanks. Also, I edited for clarification.

Comment: This answer would be even better if you talk about World Tournaments. This is a case where you will have OCG and TCG cards playing against each other. My recollection is that if a card is banned on either the TCG or OCG ban list, you cannot use it in your deck during the World Tournaments.

Comment: @Thunderforge I think that World Tournament is different for OGC and TCG. The world tournament, IIRC, you can only use TCG banlist, and can't use OCG banlist.... Will check yo be sure though

Comment: [According to the Yu-Gi-Oh! Wiki](https://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Forbidden#World_Championship), “During World Championship tournaments, all cards are automatically set to their lowest allowed status in any region” (in addition to some other restrictions).